# To implement a search program in C program using system calls for files and directories

Tags: c, linux, unix, command-line, command-line-arguments

I designed a C code to implement a search program in C program using system calls for files and directories and add additional features to the search program implemented.

```
/*
Name:
BlazerId:
Project #:
To compile: gcc -o search search.c
To run: ./search [-v] [-L size_limit] [-s pattern] [-d max_depth] [-t file_type] [-e command] [-E command] [directory]
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/*
    Function: file_permissions
    Description: Prints the permissions of a file.
    Parameters:
        - mode: File mode
    Returns: None
*/
void file_permissions(mode_t mode) {
    char permissions[10];
    permissions[0] = (S_ISDIR(mode)) ? 'd' : '-';
    permissions[1] = (mode & S_IRUSR) ? 'r' : '-';
    permissions[2] = (mode & S_IWUSR) ? 'w' : '-';
    permissions[3] = (mode & S_IXUSR) ? 'x' : '-';
    permissions[4] = (mode & S_IRGRP) ? 'r' : '-';
    permissions[5] = (mode & S_IWGRP) ? 'w' : '-';
    permissions[6] = (mode & S_IXGRP) ? 'x' : '-';
    permissions[7] = (mode & S_IROTH) ? 'r' : '-';
    permissions[8] = (mode & S_IWOTH) ? 'w' : '-';
    permissions[9] = (mode & S_IXOTH) ? 'x' : '-';
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(permissions); i++) {
        putchar(permissions[i]);
    }
}

/*
    Function: last_modify
    Description: Prints the last modification time of a file.
    Parameters:
        - last_time: Last modification time
    Returns: None
*/
void last_modify(time_t last_time) {
    char start_time[30];
    struct tm *time_info = localtime(&last_time);
    strftime(start_time, sizeof(start_time), "%b %d %H:%M", time_info);
    printf(" Last modified: %s\n", start_time);
}

/*
    Function: file_size
    Description: Prints the size of a file.
    Parameters:
        - file_size: File size
    Returns: None
*/
void file_size(off_t file_size) {
    printf(" Size: %lld bytes\n", (long long) file_size);
}

/*
    Function: symlink_path
    Description: Prints the target path of a symbolic link.
    Parameters:
        - filepath: Path of the symbolic link
    Returns: None
*/
void symlink_path(const char *filepath) {
    char link_target[PATH_MAX];
    ssize_t len_symlnk = readlink(filepath, link_target, sizeof(link_target) - 1);
    if (len_symlnk == -1) {
        perror("readlink");
        return;
    }
    link_target[len_symlnk] = '\0';
    printf("%s->%s\n", filepath, link_target);
}

/*
    Function: file_info
    Description: Prints information about a file, including permissions, size, last modified time, and symbolic link target.
                 Executes a specified Unix command if provided.
    Parameters:
        - path: Path of the file
        - file_meta: File metadata
        - verbose: Verbose mode flag
        - unix_command: Unix command to execute
    Returns: None
*/
void file_info(const char *path, struct stat *file_meta, int verbose, const char *unix_command) {
    if (verbose) {
        if (S_ISLNK(file_meta->st_mode)) {
            symlink_path(path);
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", path);
        }
        file_size(file_meta->st_size);
        last_modify(file_meta->st_mtime);
        file_permissions(file_meta->st_mode);
    } else {
        if (S_ISLNK(file_meta->st_mode)) {
            symlink_path(path);
        } else {
            printf("%s\n", path);
        }
    }

    // Execute specified Unix command using fork/exec/wait
    if (unix_command != NULL) {
        char *cmd_copy = strdup(unix_command);
        char *token = strtok(cmd_copy, " ");
        char *tar_file_name = NULL;
        while (token != NULL) {
            tar_file_name = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else if (pid == 0) {  // Child process
            execlp("tar", "tar", "rvf", tar_file_name, path, NULL);
            perror("execlp");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        } else {  // Parent process
            int status;
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
            if (WIFEXITED(status) && WEXITSTATUS(status) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "tar command failed for file: %s\n", path);
            }
        }

        free(cmd_copy);
    }
}

/*
    Function: list_filedir
    Description: Recursively lists files and directories in a specified directory hierarchy.
    Parameters:
        - path: Directory path
        - current_level: Current level of directory hierarchy
        - verbose: Verbose mode flag
        - file_size_threshold: Minimum file size threshold
        - pattern: Pattern to match filenames
        - depth_limit: Maximum directory traversal depth
        - file_type: File type filter (0: all files, 1: regular files, 2: directories)
        - unix_command: Unix command to execute
        - unix_command_args: Arguments for the Unix command
    Returns: None
*/
void list_filedir(const char *path, int current_level, int verbose, long file_size_threshold, const char *pattern, int depth_limit, int file_type, const char *unix_command, char * const* unix_command_args) {
    DIR *dir = opendir(path);
    if (dir == NULL) {
        perror("opendir");
        return;
    }
    struct dirent *ent;
    struct stat ent_st;
    char full_path[PATH_MAX];
    while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(ent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(ent->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        snprintf(full_path, sizeof(full_path), "%s/%s", path, ent->d_name);
        if (lstat(full_path, &ent_st) == -1) {
            perror("lstat");
            continue;
        }
        int meets_size_threshold = (file_size_threshold == -1 || ent_st.st_size >= file_size_threshold);
        int matches_pattern = (pattern == NULL || strstr(ent->d_name, pattern) != NULL);
        int is_regular_file = S_ISREG(ent_st.st_mode);
        int is_directory = S_ISDIR(ent_st.st_mode);

        if (file_type == 1 && !is_regular_file) { // List regular files only
            continue;
        } else if (file_type == 2 && !is_directory) { // List directories only
            continue;
        }

        if (meets_size_threshold && matches_pattern) {
            printf("%*s", current_level * 4, "");
            file_info(full_path, &ent_st, verbose, unix_command);
        }

        if (is_directory && current_level < depth_limit) {
            list_filedir(full_path, current_level + 1, verbose, file_size_threshold, pattern, depth_limit, file_type, unix_command, unix_command_args);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int verbose_flag = 0;
    long size_limit = -1;
    int max_depth = INT_MAX;
    char *pattern = NULL;
    int file_type = 0; // 0: all files, 1: regular files, 2: directories
    const char *command = NULL;
    char * const *command_args = NULL;

    int option;
    while ((option = getopt(argc, argv, "vL:s:d:t:e:E:")) != -1) {
        switch (option) {
            case 'v':
                verbose_flag = 1;
                break;
            case 'L':
                size_limit = strtol(optarg, NULL, 10);
                break;
            case 's':
                pattern = optarg;
                break;
            case 'd':
                max_depth = strtol(optarg, NULL, 10);
                break;
            case 't':
                if (strcmp(optarg, "f") == 0) {
                    file_type = 1; // List regular files only
                } else if (strcmp(optarg, "d") == 0) {
                    file_type = 2; // List directories only
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid argument for -t option\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                break;
            case 'e':
                command = optarg;
                break;
            case 'E':
                command = optarg;
                // Parse additional arguments for the command
                command_args = &argv[optind];
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-v] [-L size_limit] [-s pattern] [-d max_depth] [-t file_type] [-e command] [-E command] [directory]\n", argv[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    char *base_path = (optind < argc) ? argv[optind] : ".";
    list_filedir(base_path, 0, verbose_flag, size_limit, pattern, max_depth, file_type, command, command_args);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the **readme.md** file of the program:

````
# Search Program

This program allows you to search for files and directories in a specified directory hierarchy. Only for Unix operating systems.

# Install require packages

The very first step is to update the packages, run this command:
```bash
ssudo apt update
```
Install **make** package using the following commnad:
```bash
sudo apt install make
```
Install **gcc** using the following commnad:
```bash
sudo apt install build-essential
```
# Compilation

To compile the C source file into an executable, follow the below steps:
- Place search.c and the Makefile in the same directory.
- Open a terminal and navigate to the directory containing the files.
- Run the following command in terminal:
```bash
gcc -o search search.c
```
#  Execution

After compilation, you can run the executable program using the following command:
```bash
./search [-v] [-L size_limit] [-s pattern] [-d max_depth] [-t file_type] [-e command] [-E command] [directory]
```
Options
-v: Verbose mode (optional).
-L size_limit: Limit the size of files to be listed (optional).
-s pattern: Search for files matching a specific pattern (optional).
-d max_depth: Specify the maximum depth of directory traversal (optional).
-t file_type: Specify the type of files to list (0 for all files, 1 for regular files, 2 for directories) (optional).
-e command: Execute the specified Unix command for each file (optional).
-E command: Execute the specified Unix command using all file names as arguments (optional).

# Citation

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html
https://www.javatpoint.com/command-line-arguments-in-c
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_command_line_arguments.htm
https://www.upgrad.com/tutorials/software-engineering/c-tutorial/command-line-arguments-in-c/
````

My C code successfully implement a search program using system calls for files and directories. But this code failed to execute Unix-command. I tried to include this features in code. But this not work.

**Additional features need to include in the C code:**

1. Implementation of search that executes the UNIX command with optional arguments for each matching file using fork/exec/wait
2. Implementation of search that lists the files and directories in the specified format when executed with multiple options (combination of `-L`, `-s` and `-e`/`-E`)

`-e "<unix-command with arguments>"` For each file that matches the search criteria the UNIX command specified with arguments must be executed.

`-E "<unix-command with arguments>"` The list of files that matches the search criteria must be provided as an argument to the UNIX command specified.

Note that with the “`-e`” option, the UNIX command is executed for each file whereas with the “`-E`” option the UNIX command is executed only once but uses all the file names as arguments. You must use fork/exec/wait to create a new process to execute the UNIX command.
The UNIX command and any optional arguments are enclosed within double quotes. The program should support -e or -E options in combination with `-L` and `-s` options. You can assume that the `-e` or `-E` options appear after the `-L` and `-s` options.

**Here are some examples of commands with description:**

`$./search -L 1024 -e "ls -l"` List all files with size >= 1024 bytes in the current directory, and execute the command "`ls -l`" on each file (ignore directories)

`$./search -s jpg 3 -E "tar cvf jpg.tar"` List all files that have the substring “jpg” in their filename or directory name with depth <=3 relative to the current directory, and creates a tar file named jpg.tar that contains these files

`$./serch -L 1024 -s jpg 3 -e "wc -l"` List all files that have the substring “jpg” in their filename with depth <=3 relative to the current directory and size >= 1024, and execute the command "`wc -l`" on each file (ignore directories)

The above commands are just examples. This code must run with all kinds unix-command with arguments with `-e` and `-E` option.

Comment: Reduce your post to just the part with the problem. If the problem is that your program is failing to execute some Unix command, then make a small version of your program that **only** attempts to execute the Unix command. Nobody cares that it is part of a larger program to search directories, and they should not have to look through all the code to find the part with the problem you are asking about. Edit the post to provide a [mre].

Comment: Note that there is an inconsistency between receiving most of the command to execute, including options, as a single argument on one hand, and feeding one or more additional arguments to it via the program on the other hand.  Standard utilities that perform similar services, such as `find -exec` and `xargs`, instead take the command to execute as possibly multiple arguments that do not require any word splitting within the program.

Comment: You don't really show any code for the `-E` case. You just set `command` and `command_args`. But, then you call `list_filedir`. You would need a separate function that takes the `argv` values that come _after_ `-E` and do `fork/execvp/wait`, similar to what you do in `file_info`